# Facebook 60 day access token

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am currently having issues with the 60 day access_token. I grab the fansite access_token thru /me/applications and I want to post on them, without the need for refreshing the site every 2 hours.

When I'm parsing the token for the fansite in the way facebook provides it just throws an error.

The login is handled thru Javascript and in the background with the PHP SDK.

Greetings,
Moritz

Edit:

`{"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"}` is the error.

Code is this:

```
$attachment = array('message' => $post['title'],
                        'link' => $unique,
                        'actions' => '{"name": "Fanseiten Admin?", "link": "http://google.com"}',
                        'access_token' => $page['access_token']);
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$page['pageid'].'/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

Simply pushes to a site with the access token stored in a database.

Comment: What is the code? what is the error? What are you talking about? :)

Comment: Hey,

I updated the main text.

Comment: Have you tried putting the page access token on as a query string parameter instead of a form post parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: extend the base_facebook.php class with following and call

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($facebook->getExtendedAccessToken());
```

The access_token for apps also now extends to 60 days.

```
public function getExtendedAccessToken(){

    try {
        // need to circumvent json_decode by calling _oauthRequest
        // directly, since response isn't JSON format.
        $access_token_response =
            $this->_oauthRequest(
                $this->getUrl('graph', '/oauth/access_token'), array(
                    'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                    'client_secret' => $this->getAppSecret(),
                    'grant_type'=>'fb_exchange_token',
                    'fb_exchange_token'=>$this->getAccessToken()
                )
            );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // most likely that user very recently revoked authorization.
        // In any event, we don't have an access token, so say so.
        return false;
    }

    if (empty($access_token_response)) {
        return false;
    }

    $response_params = array();
    parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);
    if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
        return false;
    }

    return $response_params['access_token'];
}
```